# What did Freud intend as the referent of 'Das Es' (Latin: 'id')? Why didn't he name with the referent?

Tags: terminology, freud

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego#Translation) states:

> The terms "id", "ego", and "super-ego" are not Freud's own. They are latinisations by his translator [James Strachey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Strachey). Freud himself wrote of "***[das](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/das#German) [Es](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Es#German)***",[[5]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego#cite_note-Es-5) "***das [Ich](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ich)***",[[19]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego#cite_note-Ich-19) and "***das [Über-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%BCber-)Ich***"[[28]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego#cite_note-.C3.9Cber-Ich-28)—respectively, "the It", "the I", and "the Over-I" (or "I above"); thus to the German reader, Freud's original terms are more or less self-explanatory. [...]

1. What's the referent of the German pronoun 'Es'?
2. Why didn't Freud name (the concept known as ⟨Es⟩) with the referent itself instead? I.e., wouldn't naming ⟨Es⟩ as ['Instinkt'](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-german/instinct) to mean ['instinctual drive'](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/3975) make the term easier to understand and more self-explanatory?

Comment: See https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/18092/7001 re why this question is off-topic here.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg - I don't agree - see [here](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2292/community-answer-for-questions-on-freudian-psychology)

Comment: This is a great question! It's a shame that the only answer didn't quite grasp what you were asking. I'm struggling with the same problem and I stumbled upon an interesting discovery thanks to your insight. In Spanish (even when it's closer to Latin than english, the native language of James Strachey) the accademic-accepted translations are Ello, Yo, Super-Yo, which are (roughly) direct translations to das Es, das Ich, and das Über-Ich. Im not sure though why we didn't follow the "Id" translation, perhaps it was better to just sticking to the original Freud concept.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**
Freud din't come up with that terminology, he borrowed it from his contemporaries.

**Background**
According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego) Freud borrowed the term "[das Es](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2361/what-is-the-difference-between-ist-and-es)" from [Georg Groddeck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Groddeck), a German physician to whose unconventional ideas Freud was much attracted (Groddeck's translators render the term in English also as "the It").

Nietzsche, who is thought to have [influenced Freud](https://philosophynow.org/issues/68/Psychoanalysis_and_Philosophy_II) also often used the German pronoun das Es. Freud’s English translator indeed used the Latin word 'id'.